# NativeScript Angular, Google Play: This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

Tags: build, apk, nativescript, google-play-console, nativescript-angular

I cannot rollout Android app, because I get this error on Google Play Console:

> Error This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit
>   requirement
>
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but
>   they only have 32-bit native code: 17.
>
> Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App
>   Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device
>   architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids
>   increasing the overall size of your app.

I have tried putting proper directive in app.gradle / defaultConfig:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

and I also tried

```
ndk {
  abiFilters.clear()
}
```

and I still get the same error.

How do I include 64bit code in the compiled APK?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest NativeScript CLI (version 6.1.x) - the support for X86_64 was added in one of the recent versions of the CLI